# Why are the blessing(s) preceding the Haftarah printed and chanted with trope notes?

Tags: blessing, trop-cantillation, haftarah

There is a reason that I placed the plural "s" in parentheses for my question. I noticed that only the blessings preceding the haftarah have trope notes. Since this is not part of the haftarah itself, why does the blessing need any trope?

2nd question - It looks like the wording is actually two blessings as the common introductory phrase "Baruch ata Hashem" appears twice. However the trope has an etnachta at the end of the first blessing rather than a sof pasuk. Thus, it seems that these two blessings are combined as one "long one" as if it were a single pasuk. Is it one or two brachot?

3rd question - Why is there no trope for the blessings AFTER the Haftarah?

Comment: No source, my own thoughts as a קורא -- the default in reading is Torah _trup_, but the bracha helps switch from "Torah mode" to "Haftorah mode"

Comment: Which would explain first and third questions IMO

Comment: @Shokhet - interesting idea. However, even though Kaddish is said before Maftir, technically, maftir is "attached" to the Haftarah, and I think that's one of the reasons for doing Kaddish. Although, admittedly, on Minchah of fast days, there is no Kaddish befor reading Haftarah, so, at least there, your idea has a stronger reason.

Comment: It is one blessing at the beginning of the haftara, not two. There are two type of brachot. They are "long brachot" and "short brachot." Long brachot start and end with _baruch ata Hashem_. The most famous example is the first bracha of shmoneh esrei. A "short bracha" is one that only consists of _baruch ata Hashem_, blank. Sometimes when there are multiple long brachot in a series, the opening baruch is eliminated in the second and subsequent ones. Examples include most brachot in shmoneh esrei and the second and third brachot in birkat hamazon

Comment: Speaking from experience, that Kaddish is NOT enough to break up the two _trup_ schemes -- in real life, that bracha is very very useful

Comment: @Daniel That is true for Ashkenazim but other communities treat it as two blessings.

Comment: http://forum.otzar.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=17573

Answer (score 3):

I once read Megillat Esther privately to an elderly student of R [Ahron Soloveichik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahron_Soloveichik) who could not attend a public reading for health reasons. Before he recited the blessings he told me that R Ahron Soloveichik once reported to him that his grandfather, R [Chaim Soloveitchik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Soloveitchik), believed that the blessings attached to the Torah readings are part of the Mitzva of reading the Torah and should thus be said in the same tune as the reading. For this reason, apparently, R Chaim Soloveitchik would practice saying the blessings with the High Holiday tune in preparation for the Aliyah his synagogue would give him on Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur. (I have never seen this recorded elsewhere.)

Because of this, the man I was reading to sang (or, at least tried to sing) the blessings before the Megillah in the traditional tune associated with those blessings on Purim. This might help answer your first question.

Answer (score 1):

1. In my own experience as a קורא (reader of the Torah), I have appreciated
   the placement of *trup* on the *bracha* before the Haftorah as a way
   to "get in the mode" of laining with the Haftorah *trup*, as it can
   be hard to remember not to use the Torah *trup* (and, sometimes,
   even if you do remember, it's *still* hard to switch).
2. As Daniel [said](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43324/why-are-the-blessings-preceding-the-haftarah-printed-and-chanted-with-trope-no#comment112247_43324), that bracha is really just one bracha -- it's a ברכה ארוכה "long bracha," that starts with שם ומלכות and ends (after a lot of words) with the "second" bracha.
3. According to what I wrote in the first point, there would be no need for the Haftorah *trup* after the Haftorah, because [while hopefully you *were* able to get into the Haftorah mode!] now there is no longer any need to be in that mode.

---

*As mentioned in the comments, I have no source for this and this is entirely my own opinion. A more authoritative answer citing sources would be greatly appreciated!*

Comment: Appreciate the answer and effort. Not ready to upvote or accept, yet. Would like to see better sources if there are any.

Comment: But of course....I would love to see sourced answers as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer to 1 and 3.

1. The trop in the haftara beracha serves as a warm up so the layner can adjust to the haftarah trop after using the different torah trop.

   1. When I read the after beracha, I do read it with a tune just as I read the before beracha.