# Hatzi Kaddish melody using Haftarah nusach

Tags: shabbat, torah-service, music, trop-cantillation, nusach-ashkenaz

Some years ago I visited a shul where the hazzan chanted Hatzi Kaddish of the Shabbat Torah service in the nusach of the Haftarah.  I seem to recall it started with mapach pashtah munach zokeif-katon.

I would love to learn this, but have not found any source for the te'amim to use (or overlay).  Would anybody have this?

This melody might have been that hazzan's personal custom.  I did email him and request his te'amim, but I never heard back.

Comment: I have heard from a teacher at the Belz School of Music that this is how it "should" be done.  The Kaddish tune alerts people to what is upcoming, so the tune for kaddish after Torah reading sounds like haftara, and the kaddish just before mussaf sounds like mussaf.

Comment: Would you happen to have contact information for that teacher?

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen Wouldn't that seem to more apply to the [blessing before the haftara](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43324/759) than to kaddish?

Comment: @DoubleAA it applies there too, and perhaps more commonly for blessing before haftara, but speaker definitely said it in regard to kaddishes, as the OP asked.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen I went to Belz school several years ago. Would you recall who told you this? Was it Cantor Beer?

Comment: Suggestion - If you can get a copy of the Hertz Chumash, the back has musical notation for each trope note. That may help you construct it, though it requires more effort than hearing a recording of the Kaddish done this way. If it in the same format as the blessings, you can probably assume the same note order, no?

Comment: @DanF: That's a great idea!  All I need now is the trope notations.

Comment: this guy put trop to kaddish https://opensiddur.org/prayers/solilunar/weekdays/amidah-weekday/weekday-amidah-and-kaddish-with-taamei-hamiqra/