# I'm looking for regional melodies for the brachot for before and after chanting Torah in an Aliyah

Tags: blessing, torah-reading, music, minhagim

I'm looking for regional melodies for the brachot sung before and after chanting Torah in an aliyah.

I'd love to know the Ukrainian, the Belarusian, the Yemenite, the Ethiopian, the Iraqi, the Egyptian, the Syrian (khalabi), and the oldest of the Indian, specifically.

Any one of these would be appreciated, so please answer about any part of this you know.

Is anyone working on a data base where one could have all of the regional melodies for each bracha? The ones I've seen are not globally inclusive.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Sabra and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: A quick search of this site didn't turn up the exact brachot you're looking for,, but the site may be useful to you regardless: http://www.sephardichazzanut.com/default.htm

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43339/759

Comment: Check out the recordings of the National Library of Israel: https://merhav.nli.org.il/primo-explore/search?query=any,contains,%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94&tab=default_tab&search_scope=Local&vid=NLI&mfacet=rtype,include,ethnographic-recording,1&mfacet=tlevel,include,online_resources,2&offset=0